# How to Implement an animation of a Spring mass System in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Please I'm trying to implement an animation effect in Malab.  Essentially, it is the emulation of a mass-spring system. I am implementing an animation of a spring mass system in Matlab. A solid mass(m) is attached to a coil spring. The spring is rigidly fixed at one end and the spring and the attached mass are free to move in a line along a horizontal surface. as shown below :

fixed end           spring         attached mass

|-///////////////////////[|||||||]

|-----------------------------------------x=0----------------> x-axis

Figure 1. The spring-mass system in equilibrium

We Assume that : 
(1) if the spring is compressed by a length of L meters, then it exerts on the mass a force of k*L in the direction of the positive x-axis;
(2) if the spring is stretched by a length of L, then it exerts on the mass a force of k*L in the direction of the negative x-axis.
(3) the Spring is a linear spring.

This is the mathematical model used to implement this diagram above,

x= e^(-h/2m)t (C1 cos (ɷt) + C2 sin (ɷt))

Vo = (-h)/2m C1 + C2 ɷ

where C1 = Xo ,  C2=1/ɷ  (Vo +h/2m xo) and  ɷ =√(4mk- h^2 )/2m

for X values ranging from 0,1,2 ... n.
with these input parameters :

V0 -- initial velocity (double precision)
X0 -- initial position (double precision)
k, -- spring constant (positive) (double precision)
m -- mass of object (double precision)
h -- time step (double precision)

```
I need to implement this model in a spring mass system as shown above in Matlab. I have however, managed to come up with these :

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
h1=handles.axes1;
h2=handles.axes2;
h3=handles.axes3;
h4=handles.axes4;


t=0:0.1:10;
M=str2num(get(handles.M_value,'String'));
H=str2num(get(handles.H_value,'String'));
K=str2num(get(handles.K_value,'String'));
Xo=str2num(get(handles.Initial_X_value, 'String'));
Vo=str2num(get(handles.Initial_V_value, 'String'));

C1=Xo;
W=((4*M*K-H^2)^0.5)/(2*M);
C2=(1/W)*(Vo+H/(2*M)*Xo);

X=exp(-H/(2*M).*t).*(C1*cos(W.*t)+C2*sin(W.*t));
V=exp(-H/(2*M).*t).*((-H/(2*M)*C1+W*C2).*cos(W.*t)-(H/(2*M)*C2+W*C1).*sin(W.*t));

axes(h1);
plot(t,X,'b.','MarkerSize',5);
axes(h3);
plot(X,V,'b.','MarkerSize',5);
axes(h2);
plot(t,V,'b.','MarkerSize',5);

% this graph displays the animation of the Spring mass system's movement
axes(h4);
clc
clear;
%Set an array of abscissas
x=-10:0.1:10;
% We then get an array of cordinates
y=x.*x;
% we then represent the gradual construction of the schedule by
%Looping from #1 throughout the entire elements in the array x

for j=1:length(x)
    %Build a graph of the points from the first to the j-th
    plot(x(1:j),y(1:j),'-b', 'LineWidth' , 1)
    %Draw the background grid
    grid on
    %Fix a graph
    hold on
    %Draw a point on the graph (the end point of the graph)
    plot(x(j),y(j), '.g' , 'MarkerSize', 20)
    %Fix Coordinates of the plane: from 0 to 5 for the x axis and from 0 to
    %5 on the y axis.
    axis([-10 10 0 100]) 
    %Turn off the lock to draw a graph for the next redrawing
    hold off
    %remember the current frame
    F(j)= getframe;

end
```

[Figure showing the portrait diagrams for the 4 plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nod5R.jpg)
 for the 3 portraits but the final portrait just doesn't seem to display as I need it to. I humbly request your indulgence to solve this challenge. Thank You.

Comment: What do you mean by "`but the final portrait just doesn't seem to display as I need it to`"?

Comment: I run your code on my PC and four plots show, including the last one which is an animation. I did some modifications since I don't have your exact figure. I changed all lines up to `Vo=str2num...` with the following `h1=subplot(2,2,1);
h2=subplot(2,2,2);
h3=subplot(2,2,3);
h4=subplot(2,2,4);


t=0:0.1:10;
M=1;
H=0.1;
K=2;
Xo=2;
Vo=3;` I suggest you see if this does run well for you, and that may help you find the problem.

Comment: Please Andreas, I intend to display an animation of this :       fixed end           spring         attached mass

|-/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\[|||||||]

|-----------------------------------------x=0----------------> x-axis

Figure 1. The spring-mass system in equilibrium                                                                                 portrait on the 4th plot